# extract values/renaming filename in python

Tags: python, split, extract, wildcard, rename

I am trying to use python to rename a filename which contains values such as:  `~test1~test2~filename.csv`

I want to rename the file to filename.csv.  The tildes being my separator for the first two words, and I do not want those words in my finale file name.  These words are variables.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I am fairly new to python so am trying to learn regular expression, split/joint for extracting.  I can do a rename of a straight file name, but am trying to extract the file name based on the words consistent pattern/character to extract what I need.

Comment: I've done glob in conjunction with .rename, but that doesn't account for the wildcards.

Comment: It is usually helpful to include that information on the question it self, usually with the exact code you've tried. It shows people that you have spent time trying on your own before posting the question and also gives them a starting point on where to look for problems or sources of confusion for you. Just a friendly tip.

Comment: I do apologize.  I am learning python, and this is my first time using the site.  I will read on the etiquette and improve my efforts.  Thank you!

Comment: If everyone had that attitude :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the words change for each file name its best to search a directory for files that match a pattern. [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) does that for you.

If you have a directory like this:

```
.
├── ~a~b~c.csv
├── file.csv
├── ~foo~bar~f1.csv
└── hello.txt
```

Then running this:

```
import os, glob
for f in glob.glob('~*~*~*.csv'):
    os.rename(f,f.split('~')[-1])
```

Will give you:

```
.
├── c.csv
├── f1.csv
├── file.csv
└── hello.txt
```

Comment: Good answer. Much more generic compared to my proposal.

Comment: Supremely helpful...thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

myfilename = "~test1~test2~filename.csv"

for filename in os.listdir("."):
   if filename == myfilename:
       myfilename_new = myfilename.split("~")[-1]
       os.rename(filename, myfilename_new)
```

Assuming of course that your original file `~test1~test2~filename.csv` exists in the "current/same  directory" that this python script runs.

Hope this helps you in your learning journey!

Welcome to Python!